# Do Drupal Users Have Authority

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have started setting up a Drupal web site.  I am not used to this particular CMS.  So I do not know what it means when people register.  I have already gotten notices that people are trying to sign up.

I am a bit familiar with a phpbb but not drupal. If I get these people permissions or allow them to be members, what powers do they have. Could they be spam bots? Could they wreck havoc on the web site? Could they make menus and content without me knowing about it?

Answer (score 5):

Out of the box, Drupal recognizes only two types of site visitors - those who are logged in (known as 'Authenticated' users in Drupal community) and those who are not (known as 'Anonymous' users in Drupal community). The exception is the [first user created (user/1)](https://drupal.org/node/22284).

To make things more clear:

- **Administrator** - You can assign this role to registered users and it is assigned to all available permissions on your site. Only give it to people you trust!
- **Site maintainer** - This role belongs to the site creator and includes all permissions.
- **Anonymous** - All unregistered site visitors have the anonymous user role. Anyone who visits your site, but isn't logged in, has the anonymous user role.
- **Authenticated** - All registered and logged-in users have the authenticated user role.

You can create and assign one or more "user roles" to each visitor in Drupal easily.

You can go through this [Drupal community doc](https://drupal.org/node/120614) for more information on how to create custom roles with customized permissions that you can assign to your authenticated users.